# Etimologia dell'utilizzo avverbiale di "proprio"

Tags: etymology, adjectives, adverbs, latin

Da Treccani, "proprio" può essere utilizzato sia come aggettivo (ciascuno porti il *proprio* bicchiere) che come avverbio (Anna è *proprio* bella). Sempre da Treccani, l'etimologia è "dal lat. proprius, prob. dalla locuz. pro privo «a titolo privato, personale»" che è plausibile per l'aggettivo, ma non riesco a figurarmi come possa aver portato all'utilizzo avverbiale.
**Qual è l'etimologia di "proprio" come avverbio**, se diversa da quella menzionata? Se è la stessa, come si è giunti ad utilizzarlo con accezione rafforzativa?

Comment: Benvenuto! Trovo la domanda interessante. Però, più che articolo direi che *proprio* si può usare come possessivo.

Comment: Dove dici “articolo” intendi “aggettivo”, vero?

Comment: Sono d'accordo con @DaG e egreg: quello che appare nel Treccani è: «agg. e avv.».

Comment: @DaG sì scusami, mi sono confuso, ho modificato il post

Comment: Credo che, come avverbio, *proprio* vada inteso come *propriamente*: cioè con proprietà, con ragione. Per questo ritengo che l'etimologia sia la stessa.